# How do I use a nodejs promise value in another function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having two functions in nodejs. One looks like this

```
function checkAdd (
  address /* : string | void */
) /* :Promise<Object[]> */ {

  var convertToLowerCase = address.toLowerCase()

    return Promise.resolve()

    .then(() => {
      var allMatch = addressesAsJson.filter((record) => record.address === convertToLowerCase)

 });

}
```

There's another function like this

```
function saveNewAd(
  address /* :?string | void */, cb
) /* :Promise<string> */ {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {


    var checkAddress = checkAddressAvailable(address)

    var addressAvailableResult = checkAddressAvailable(address)

    var seperatedAddress = address.split(',') 
    var firstAddLine  = capitalFirstLetter(seperatedAddress[0])
    var secondAddLine = seperatedAddress[1].toUpperCase()
    var thirdAddLine =  seperatedAddress[2].toUpperCase()

    var displayAddress = firstAddLine + ',' + secondAddLine + ',' + thirdAddLine

    addressesAsJson.push({"address": address , "display" : displayAddress})    
    fs.writeFile(jsonListPath, JSON.stringify(addressesAsJson), (err) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      resolve("New address is saved")

    })


  });
}
```

Inside saveNewAd, I want to check the allMatch length and if it's more than 0, I need to execute the function body of saveNewAd. But it's not working. This is what I tried. Please help me to solve this issue

```
function saveNewAd(
  address /* :?string | void */, cb
) /* :Promise<string> */ {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {

    var results = checkAdd(address)

    if(results.length>0){

   /*same function body as above method*/

    })
    }else{
    console.log("Error")
    }

  });
}
```

Comment: you will need to use chaining make the checking inside the then that is returned by the function and not inside the function call as promise are async

Comment: `return Promise.resolve()` why????

Comment: @JonasW. - In  checkAdd? Can I use it without?

Comment: I think you dont get the basic principles of asynchronous code...

Comment: @JonasW. Yes I'm a newbie, have to study. But this is urgent project which has to send within hour..pleae help

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of chaining, i.e. first finding out `allMatch` asynchronously and then passing this value down through `.then()` to `saveNewAd` function as an argument. Note that the `.then()` function actually returns a new promise, different from the original.

```
function checkAdd (
  address /* : string | void */
) /* :Promise<Object[]> */ {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
    var convertToLowerCase = address.toLowerCase();

    var allMatch = addressesAsJson.filter((record) => record.address);

    resolve(allMatch);
  }
}

checkAdd()
.then((allMatch) => {
   saveNewAd(address, cb, allMatch); // now you can use allMatch as an argument in this function
}
===
```

MDN docs: [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).